# How to close the current tab in the server side button click?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, cross-browser

I try to close my current tab after confirm so i put the following code at the end of my confirm button , but the tab doesn't close !

---

```
   string jScript = "<script>close_window();</script>";
   ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "keyClientBlock", jScript);
```

Comment: Seeing as we're not working on this project with you, do you think you could provide a little more context to the problem?

Comment: Did you get a error message?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to close the current window, you could try this:

```
string jScript = "<script>window.close();</script>";
ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "keyClientBlock", jScript);
```

Answer (score 1):

This might help

```
Response.Write("<script>parent.close_window();</script>");
```

Answer (score 1):

I Just Add Following code on button.

```
OnClientClick="javascript:window.close();"
```