# Unable to close current window

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am Unable to close current asp.net page using C# code. I tried:

```
ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page.GetType(), 
                                       "script", 
                                       "window.close();", 
                                       true);
```

I am not getting any error, but it doesn't work.

Comment: I am not getting any error

Comment: tried this but no luck :(

Comment: Do you have an update panel?

Comment: Yes I have update panel

Comment: try `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following link

[Programmatically close aspx page from code behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375406/programmatically-close-aspx-page-from-code-behind)

Based on the scenario it may very. Please read the above thread replies

Also the following link shows the same question

[How to close the current tab in the server side button click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20197918/how-to-close-the-current-tab-in-the-server-side-button-click)

Comment: in this "Programmatically close aspx page from code behind" marked answer is closing window but it does not perform other things written on button click event.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), 
   "closePage", 
   "window.close();",
    true);
```

Comment: This is also not working

Comment: Let's try cheating. Use this: Response.Write("<script language=javascript>this.window.opener = null;window.open('','_self'); window.close();</script>"); OR Respose.Write("<script>window.close()</script>");